# Javascript filter not working with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, filter

Let's assume I have this array :

```
array = [{ 
    name: 'my post',
    categories: [{
        slug: 'a-cat',
        name: 'A Category'
    }
},
{ 
    name: 'my other post',
    categories: [{
        slug: 'another-category',
        name: 'Another Category'
    },
    {
        slug: 'a-cat',
        name: 'A Category'
    }
},
]
```

Now, I would like to filter it to get all element that contain the category `another-category`, this is what i've tried so far, but nothing ends up in the `filteredArray`

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(function (item) {
    return item.categories.forEach(function(cat) {
        return cat.slug === 'another-category'
    })
})
```

Any thoughts on what I've done wrong ?

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'my post',
    categories: [{
      slug: 'a-cat',
      name: 'A Category'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'my other post',
    categories: [{
        slug: 'another-category',
        name: 'Another Category'
      },
      {
        slug: 'a-cat',
        name: 'A Category'
      }
    ]
  },
]


let filteredArray = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item.categories.forEach(function(cat) {
    return cat.slug === 'another-category'
  })
})

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined` which is treated as `false` in `filter`. What is your desired result?

Comment: I fixed your object and created a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you misunderstand the return value of forEach.
In your example code, `item.category.forEach()` will always return `undefined` when it finishes execution, that's why it went wrong.

In this case, you should use `Array.some()` which with return value is boolean (true/false).

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(function (item) {
    // this mean:
    //  if has ANY <cat>s in array item.categories has slug attribute equal 'another-category': 
    //  return current <item>
    return item.categories.some(function(cat) {
        return cat.slug === 'another-category'
    })
})
```

**An alternative answer is using `.every()`:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(function (item) {
        // this mean:
        //  if NOT(ALL <cat>s in array item.categories haven't .slug attribute  equal  'another-category'): 
        //  return current <item>
        return !item.categories.every(function(cat) {
            return (return cat.slug !== 'another-category')
        });
})
```

note: the `.every()` is just an additional example, in case of you guys need it in the future :)!

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is `some`. Replace `forEach` with `some`.

```
return item.categories.some(function(cat) {
    return cat.slug === 'another-category'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` method over `categories` to filter final list

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(item => {
    return item.categories.find( category => category.slug === 'another-category');
});
```